# Tree like menu ubuntu

Tags: shortcuts, menu

I would like to know if there is a way to get the a "tree-menu" on Ubuntu like in windows (see printscreen)?

I look for a solution where the user could chose any file as start point (for instance startup of the tree-menu could be /etc/emacs  or var/www/htlm  or /opt/   ...)

The number of tree-menu should be multiple : on the printscreen I have 3 tree-menu : 1"documents" 2"owncloudLA" and 3"BACKUP_AD".

I am using ubuntu 14lts.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Referring to this question you could install two indicators in your panel:

[What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available)

First one is the Gnome Classic Menu Indicator. It will bring back th Gnome Menu, which gives tree access to your installed programs. Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator
```

Second one gives you an indicator to access the places called bookmarks from your filebrowser and is called simply Places Inidicator

Download the latest version:

https://github.com/shamil/indicator-places/archive/master.zip

Extract the files

Run indicator-places.py